# MultiClients with Multithreading on AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, sockets

I am working on a project which has three WiFi modules "ESP8266-01" (they represent three servers) and I want to read from all of them at same time.
And i want to achieve that by running three clients each on on a separate Thread .
I created a special class for this purpose (called IMU1) and I run it on PC and it works fine but when I try to move this program to android it gives me this error when i press the button :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: client.app.recrive, PID: 4416
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
        at client.app.recrive.IMU1.read(IMU1.java:45)
        at client.app.recrive.MainActivity.receiveData(MainActivity.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity:

```
package client.app.recrive;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import client.app.recrive.IMU1;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn;
    private TextView tv;
    private EditText txt;
    public void receiveData(View v) throws IOException , InterruptedException{

       IMU1 imu = new IMU1("192.168.1.7", 8080, 1);
        imu.start();
        //wait until the connection is complete
        Thread.sleep(100);
        this.tv.setText(imu.read());
        imu.join();
        Log.d("wifi","finished");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        this.txt = findViewById(R.id.text);
        this.tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        this.tv.setText("");
    }
}
```

IMU1 class:

```
package client.app.recrive;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import android.util.Log;

class IMU1 extends Thread {
    private String ip = "";
    private int port = 0;
    private int id = 0;
    private float q1 = 0;
    private float q2 = 0;
    private float q3 = 0;
    private float q4 = 0;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private InputStream input;
    private String text;
    
    public IMU1(String ip, int port, int id) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.id = id;
    }
     

    public synchronized void initialize() {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(this.ip, this.port);
            this.socket = s;
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
            this.reader = r;
            } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        
    }
    
    public String read() throws IOException  {
        if ((this.reader.readLine()) == null) { ///////////////////////// The Error!
        return "Nothing!";
        } else {
        return this.reader.readLine().toString();
        }

    }

    
    public void terminate() throws IOException {
        this.socket.close();
        this.reader.close();
        //stop Thread
        
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        this.initialize();
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_700" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:insetLeft="10dp"
        android:insetRight="10dp"
        android:onClick="receiveData"
        android:text="Recieve"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/purple_700" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="client.app.recrive">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Client">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

One of the three servers that I am using to test the program:

```
package server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class server2 {

    static Socket csk;
    static byte[] data = { 111 };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
            System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 8080 ....");
            while (true) {
                try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
                
                    System.out.println("accepted");
                    
                    String text = "Hello! from server2\n";
                    while(true) {
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    //Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println("Error" + e2);
        }

    }

}
```

It indicates that the error is on the `if ((this.reader.readLine()) == null)` statement so I inverted the condition but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that `receiveData` is allowed to throw checked `Exception`s? I am asking since it it used on the `onClick` attribute.

Comment: @gthanop is right. Because you cannot just add exceptions to a method signature which is used as an onClick listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you ask a question like this, plaese learn about Threading and Java Streams first, but here is the reworked code:

Here is the receiveData method (DON'T just add exceptions to onClick methods):

```
public void receiveData(View v) {
    IMU1 imu = new IMU1("192.168.1.7", 8080, 1) {
        @Override
        public void postRun(String text) {
            tv.setText(text);
            Log.d("wifi","finished");
        }
    };
    imu.start();
}
```

And here is the reworked IMU1 class (please learn how threads work):

```
public abstract class IMU1 extends Thread {
    private final String ip;
    private final int port;
    private final int id;

    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    public IMU1(String ip, int port, int id) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.id = id;
    }

    private void initialize() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }

    private String read() throws IOException {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        return line != null ? line : "Nothing!";
    }

    private void terminate() throws IOException {
        socket.close();
        reader.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String readText;
        try {
            initialize();

            readText = read();
        } catch (Throwable tr) {
            tr.printStackTrace();

            readText = "An error occurred";
        } finally {
            try {
                terminate();
            } catch (Throwable ignored) {
            }
        }

        String text = readText;

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                postRun(text);
            }
        });
    }

    public abstract void postRun(String text);
}
```

Comment: on postRun method it syas: "Method doesn't Override method from it supercalss"

Comment: and I am sorry ,  I am new to Java (less than two months).

Comment: Did you copy it into your project directly. (So do you also have the abstract keyword in public abstract class IMU1?)

Comment: Did you copy my version of IMU1 directly into your project and replaced your receiveData method with my version? Because it should work if you did it like this

Comment: @MahmoudِِِAkhras Also does it say "Method doesn't Override method from it supercalss" inside of IMU1 or your MainActivity??

Comment: it as an import problem in the IMU1 , thank you it works

Comment: Final question what resources do you recommend to learn multi threading and Socket in deep ,for a beginner like me :)

Comment: You could start learning thrading using this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm
And server and sockets through this tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT:

Don't use the BufferedReader like you did in your IMU1's read method. You probably think that you would get the same line twice, because you first check if the read line is null and then you call readLine again to convert it into a string. BUT the second call to readLine does not return the line that you checked for null earlier. Your read method is actually reading two seperate lines.
What you probably wanted to achive is the following:

```
String line = this.reader.readLine();
if (line == null) {
    return "Nothing!";
} else {
    return line;
}
```

which you could shrink to:

```
String line = this.reader.readLine();
return line != null ? line : "Nothing!";
```

---

### Previous answer:

You would normally read from a BufferedReader like this:

```
BufferedReader r = null;
try {
    r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
    
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        // Do something with that line
    }
} finally {
    if (r != null) r.close();
}
```

You can never call readLine on a buffered reader twice and expect to always get the same line. Because once you read a line it will go to the next line.
Read line will retun null when there are no more lines to read (Stream has ended)

---

If you want to get all lines in on string do the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader r = null;
try {
    r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
    
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append('\n');
        sb.append(line);
    }
} finally {
    if (r != null) r.close();
}

String result = sb.toString(); // Now you read all lines into 'result'
```

Comment: My read() function is now like this :  
`
public String read() throws IOException  {  
  try {  
  String line;  
  while ((line = this.reader.readLine()) != null) {  
   return this.reader.readLine().toString();}  

  } finally {  
   if (this.reader != null) this.reader.close();  
   return "something";}  
 }  
`
the error is gone but it always give me "somthing".

Comment: @MahmoudِِِAkhras Noooo

Comment: @MahmoudِِِAkhras That is still getting two lines. Just use ONLY the thing I wrote under EDIT inside your read method. Do this: String line = this.reader.readLine();
return line != null ? line : "Nothing!";

Comment: That is all you need

Comment: I used the EDIT version and the error is back but this time on line :
String line = this.reader.readLine();

Comment: @MahmoudِِِAkhras is 'throws IOException' still declared on your read method. Also what is the error you are receiving

Comment: Oh I know why. Your code is completly wrong

Comment: You have no idea how threading works. I make a nother answer

Comment: I replaced the Throws with try&catch on receiveData but still nothing

Comment: the error :
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: client.app.recrive, PID: 2254
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)

Comment: The Error on line : String line = this.reader.readLine();

Comment: I put inside reader this line to ensure that the reader object is not null:
Log.d("wifi", "reader: "+this.reader);
and this what i get :
wifi: reader: java.io.BufferedReader@a512d9d8

Comment: Give me a second I'll post another answer

Comment: @MahmoudِِِAkhras I added a new answer down below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66901923/13187363). BUT PLEASE learn how to use threads and streams correctly and don't rely on other people to do it for you